# How to show user_friends data from graph api?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook-graph-api, ios8

I'm making an app on iOs and I allow user to log in with facebook. I already tested my app on simulator, **log in using facebook with 2 account that already friend**. But when I'm testing my graphpath on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/. It shows nothing.

```
{
  "id": "1001399423222952", 
  "name": "Ega Setya Putra", 
  "friends": {
    "data": [
    ], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 1290
    }
  }
}
```

and here my code on xcode, and again it shows nil

```
func getDBfriends() {
    let friendsRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me?fields=id,name,friends", parameters: nil)
    friendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler{(connection, result: AnyObject!, error) -> Void in
        if let resultdict = result as? NSDictionary{
        println("Result Dict: \(resultdict)")
        var jos = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray
        var data : NSArray = jos

        for i in 0..<data.count {
            let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as! NSDictionary
            let id = valueDict.objectForKey("id")as! String
            println("the id value is \(id)")
        }

        var friends = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray
        println("Found \(friends.count) friends")
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What data are you looking in user_friends? are you trying to get user's friendlist in full?

Comment: @kishor no according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0 user_friends only provide user using/authorized same app

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya yes, I already know that. And my second account is already using or authorized the same app. Do we have to login with actual device to achieve that? cause I'm log in using simulator only

Answer (score 3):

I thinks your graph path is wrong.I am using the following path in Objective-c and getting all my friends which are using the app.Let me know if this can help you.

```
NSData * dataFriendsList = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@&fields=id,first_name,picture,last_name,name,birthday,gender,location,link,hometown,email,work,education,bio",fbAccessToken]]];
```

And you have to take `user_friends` permission from Facebook.

Comment: which facebook sdk do you use? Are you log in using actual device or simulator? I have tried your url/graphpath on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/ and I still got nothing

Comment: Do you have any friends which are using this app. I also test this on graph explorer and its giving me my friends which is using app and this count is 25 and I am using both device and simulator.

Comment: yes I have friends using this app, but I only log in on simulator. which url do you use?

Comment: I am using the same URL which I gave in my answer.